# vim backspace triggers unset mapping

Tags: vim

I minimized my .vimrc file as below:

```
function MakeTitle()
call setline(line("."), "/**")
call append(line("."), " * @Author:\tAuthor")
endf
map <C-h> <Esc>:call MakeTitle()<CR>
```

The config allows me to press CONTROL + H to add a author header to the source file.
But When I press `BACKSPACE`, the function MakeTitle also gets triggered, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terminal, Backspace key sends Ctrl-H (usually called "BS" in ASCII); Ctrl-H is interpreted by the terminal as the "delete a character" action. In other words, there is no difference between the two. In GUI Vim you can bind those separately; in terminal, there is no way to distinguish the two, unless you change terminal settings (which I would not recommend you do).